# How to change the value of an object inside an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const nonsense = [{x: '1'}];
console.log(nonsense.indexOf({x: '1'})); // prints -1
```

I don't understand why it's printing -1 even though the specified object clearly exists in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

objects are compared by their reference, not by their values.

object inside `nonsense` array is a different object from the object you passed to `indexOf` function even though they have same key-value pairs.

Following code will give you the correct index

```js
const obj = {x: '1'};
const nonsense = [obj];

console.log(nonsense.indexOf(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

As, in javaScript the objects are compared by reference, not by the values.

```js
const nonsense = [{x: '1'}];
console.log(nonsense.map(o => o.x).indexOf('1'));
```

or, probably with better performance for larger arrays:

```
console.log(nonsense.findIndex(o => o.x ==='1'));
```